# problem to generate an exe file with maven

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark

I can generate an exe file with the maven plugin and all is fine.

But when I add the dependency of `spark-mllib`, I rerun `maven clean maven install` and the exe generated by maven doesn't run.

Java Code

```
public class App 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hello ex = new Hello();
        ex.setVisible(true);
    }
}
public class Hello extends JFrame {
    public Hello() {
        setTitle("Simple example");
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Maven Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>a</groupId>
<artifactId>a</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1</version>
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <jodatime.version>2.5</jodatime.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <!-- <maven.compiler.source>1.8.0</maven.compiler.source> <maven.compiler.target>1.8.0</maven.compiler.target> -->
</properties>

<name>a</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <dependencyConvergence />
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <id>build-massTer</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <!-- add Main-Class to manifest file -->
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>a.a.App</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>

                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
                    </configuration>

                </execution>

            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>MassTer Premium</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>launch4j</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
                        <headerType>gui</headerType>
                        <jar>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</jar>
                        <outfile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.exe</outfile>
                        <downloadUrl>http://java.com/download</downloadUrl>
                        <classPath>
                            <mainClass>a.a.App</mainClass>
                            <!-- <preCp>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</preCp> -->
                            <addDependencies>true</addDependencies>
                        </classPath>
                        <icon></icon>
                        <jre>

                            <minVersion>1.6.0_1</minVersion>
                            <maxVersion></maxVersion>

                            <initialHeapPercent>10</initialHeapPercent>
                            <maxHeapPercent>90</maxHeapPercent>

                        </jre>


                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-compiler-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.5.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <targetPath></targetPath>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/config.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>

        <resource>
            <targetPath></targetPath>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/files</directory>
            <!-- <includes> <include>configuration.xml</include> </includes> <excludes> 
                <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude> </excludes> -->
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <targetPath></targetPath>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/files/pictures</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <targetPath></targetPath>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/files/xmlFile</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
    </testResources>

</build>


<dependencies>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>junit</groupId> <artifactId>junit</artifactId> 
        <version>${junit.version}</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency> <dependency> 
        <groupId>com.joptimizer</groupId> <artifactId>joptimizer</artifactId> <version>3.5.1</version> 
        </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId> <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId> 
        <version>2.4.0</version> </dependency> -->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib -->



</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>cloudera</id>
        <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Please provide examples of your code so we can reproduce the issue and see what you have tried so far. See this advice on asking a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: */
public class App 
{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Hello ex = new Hello();
       ex.setVisible(true);
    }
}

Comment: public class Hello extends JFrame {

    public Hello() {
       setTitle("Simple example");
       setSize(300, 200);
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    


}

Comment: add it to the question not the comments. You can do this by clicking edit and pasting in the code. If you then select the code and click code sample (the curly brackets button) it will format it appropriately

Comment: Have you some error message in the maven console when you're trying to run the goal ?

Comment: no error, I run the exe file with cmd start a.exe and also no error

Comment: the jar is executable, but the exe doesn't show nothing

Comment: SebVb could ou please run my code in you machine and check the problem with that dependency Thank you